# WebRTC/PeerJS view streams without sending your own

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webrtc, peerjs

I have been looking at a way to basically be a `viewer` of WebRTC streams.
I have a local PeerJS server running on Express and using socket.io, and I can make it work stream from both/multiple users. The issue I am trying to resolve is that I have a page for users to only `View` the other streams and not transmit their on stream. The reason why I want this is because the `viewer` will not have access to any camera/mic and therefore the `navigator.mediaDevices` call will fail.

Currently, with PeerJS, i dont know of a way to answer a call without sending my own stream with `call.answer()`

I havent found any answers on SO on how to do this but i did recently run across [AppRTC](https://appr.tc/) that is powered by Google App Engine. This application DOES allow you to connect to other streams but not broadcast your own. Wondered if anyone has seen this and knows how they are doing it?

Comment: WebRTC as such has absolutely no problem with unidirectional streams. Are you limited by the socket.io API, or where exactly are you stuck…?

Comment: I guess the point i cant get past is maybe a limitation on the PeerJS side? When i answer a call i need to pass my stream in. If i try to pass in an empty MediaStream() object, thats not allowed